# Compare Numbers in Javascript array to get largest number

Tags: javascript

I seem to have the right syntax but i keep getting a NaN value, i believe it has something to do with the propagation of the array, please could you check the code and see where i am going wrong.

```
var _array = new Array();

var _first = 1;
var _second = 4;

$('#con > div').each(function(index){

    var _data = $(this).css('left').split('px')[0];
    var _class = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];

    _array[_first] = [_data];
    //_array[_second] = _class;

    _first++;
    _second++;

    if(index == 2){
        _first = 1;
        _second = 4;

        for(var i = 0; i < _array.length; i++)
        console.log(_array[i]);

        var large = Math.max.apply(Math, _array);
        console.log(large);

    }
});
```

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/LTMbr/1/

Comment: Note that your variable `_array` is _not_ an array of numbers, it is an array of arrays because you have square brackets around `_data` when you say `_array[_first] = [_data];` (unless that was just a typo in your question).

Comment: Thanks for the mention i realized that and removed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I modified it a bit to see - http://jsfiddle.net/LTMbr/4/ and your _array[0] is undefined.  So that's why your call to `Math.max` is returning NaN.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are populating your array starting at index 1. [If any of the arguments to Math.max cannot be converted to a number, NaN is returned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)
This is the case because `_array[0]` is undefined